# Laravel not sending emails on Platform.sh to SendGrid

Tags: laravel, smtp, sendgrid, laravel-spark

Im hosting a Laravel spark website on platform.sh. I have configured the environment variables within the platform.sh GUI to be what is suggested in their guides but for some reason SendGrid isn't picking up the emails.

[image]

I am using my SendGrid Log in details for username and password - I have also tried by using my API Keys.

There are no errors or anything and both SendGrid and Platform.sh are being useless saying they can't do or see anything, so im pretty lost as to where I go next. I have tried many various configuration options but none seem to have worked.

Here is the snippet of code to send the mailable in Laravel:

```
Mail::to($input['email'])->send(new BetaSignUp($referral, $referralFacebookUrl, $referralTwitterUrl));
```

Has anyone successfully got Laravel running on platform.sh, and sending emails via SMTP (SendGrid)

Thanks

**EDIT**
With the help of PSH i have run a python script they sent me to do a test on the container - this test was successful and I can see the email in SendGrid. Here is the test Script:

```
import smtplib
sender = 'info@smbstreams.live'
receivers = ['to-email@email.com']

message = """From: Deck Stream Team<info@smbstreams.live>
Reply-To: Deck Stream Team<deckstream@smbstreams.live>
To: To Person <to-email@email.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.sendgrid.net', 465)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.login("****", "****")
server.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you follow this https://docs.platform.sh/development/email.html#enablingdisabling-email

> Email support can be enabled/disabled per-environment. By default, it
>   is enabled on the master environment and disabled elsewhere. That can
>   be toggled in through the web UI or via the command line, like so:
>
> `platform environment:info enable_smtp true`

Comment: Yes I have, I am only working in the master environment at the moment so is automatically enabled and I can see this in the GUI

Comment: Please also check that is `BetaSignUp` using `Queueable`.

Comment: Why would it have to be Queueable? Can you point me to any documentation saying so please?

Comment: If there is no `Queueable`, it is oke. But if you use `Queueable` we should start Laravel worker. I just want to double about that.
BTW, please check your port and encryption to check whether it works according to https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/laravel/#before-you-begin

Comment: Yeah I will use queueable at some point but right now I would like to just get emails sending one at a time